# Problems with Uploading Script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple script that can upload files on my server and insert the details into database.

With code below I am getting two errors..

1. "Notice: Undefined variable: sExt in" ..
   I tried to fix the issue with if empty statement, but without sucess..
2. Script import numbers (1,2,3...) into Mysql if the upload filed is empty....
   I tried to fix the issue with the code below, but also without success..

   "if($_FILES['files']['name']!="")"...

Any advice?

Thank you..

My code:

```
<?php

  include_once('db.php');

if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $uploadedFiles = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $errors = array();
        $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if($file_type == "image/gif"){
            $sExt = ".gif";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg"){
            $sExt = ".jpg";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png"){
            $sExt = ".png";
        }
        if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif','.jpg','.png'))) {
            $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
        }


        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }

        $query = "INSERT into user_pics (`person_id`,`pic_name`,`pic_type`) VALUES('1','$file_name','$sExt')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors)) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);     
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
            } else {
                echo "Files Uploaded !" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }

    foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
        if (!empty($row[1])) {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = $row[0];';
            eval ($codestr);
        } else {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = NULL;';
            eval ($codestr);
        }
    }

}

?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*"> <br/>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*"> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, first I would not rely on the type to set the extension, I would pull it from the files real name ( ie not the tmp name ).  You don't have an else condition for the `$sExt` which causes everything else to bomb.  You should do else $errors[] = bla bla. There

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
 if($file_type == "image/gif"){
        $sExt = ".gif";
    } elseif($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg"){
        $sExt = ".jpg";
    } elseif($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png"){
        $sExt = ".png";
    }
    if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif','.jpg','.png'))) {
        $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
    }
```

You should do

```
   if($file_type == "image/gif"){
        $sExt = ".gif";
    } elseif($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg"){
        $sExt = ".jpg";
    } elseif($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png"){
        $sExt = ".png";
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
    }
```

Checking the extension you are setting is redundant, and this avoids the error when your varible `$sExt` is not set, by providing a default ( with else ).  This should give you the desired behaviour.

I would also move these lines

```
    $query = "INSERT into user_pics (`person_id`,`pic_name`,`pic_type`) VALUES('1','$file_name','$sExt')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    $desired_dir = "user_data/";
    if (empty($errors)) {
```

To the inside of this code block

```
  if (empty($errors)) {
        $query = "INSERT into user_pics (`person_id`,`pic_name`,`pic_type`) VALUES('1','$file_name','$sExt')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
```

That way you don't do the insert when you have something in errors...

Not sure the purpose of this

```
  foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
    if (!empty($row[1])) {
        $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = $row[0];';
        eval ($codestr);
    } else {
        $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = NULL;';
        eval ($codestr);
    }
}
```

But eval can be very very bad, I would suggest doing this another way such as using an array, however this probably could be accomplished in the first loop.  For example the `null` or `false` value could be in the else part of the check for `empty($errors)` so that if there is an error, that one is put in false like.

```
  $files = array();
  foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
    if (!empty($row[1])) {
         $files['$file' . ($key+1)] = $row[0];
    } else {
       $files['$file' . ($key+1)]  = false; //id use false instead of null in an array
    }
  }
```

You should also be careful of sql injection, although it looks like you are setting the variables, its still wise to use a prepared query just in case changes are made latter, that could open you up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you.. I just copy and paste your code, but I am still getting the same error.. Undefined variable: sExt in C:\labs\upload\multi1.php on line 31
Array ( [0] => Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only! )

Comment: Once you put the insert inside of the `if( empty($errors) )`, statement you shouldn't get that issue.  That variable is still referenced in the insert and still being called, and as we don't really want to insert if the file is not what we want, right?

Comment: quick fix: add `empty($errors) &&` to `if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif','.jpg','.png'))) {`

Comment: @MarekJanoud - checking the extension type is redundant, because the code is setting that value.  So by just putting the error in the else condition we don't need to check it against the array and thus we don't need to do that.  It's in the second code block, difference between that and the first one.

Comment: Makes hand into a gun shape, blows on index finger ... lol

Comment: Thank you guys and gals !!!

Answer (score 0):

and:

```
                                               // double slash
if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
    // file was successfuly moved
    echo "Files Uploaded !" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];                
    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
} else {                
    $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
}

foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
    if ($row[1]) { // $row[1] is never empty
        ${'file' . ($key+1)} = $row[0];
    } else {
        ${'file' . ($key+1)} = NULL;
    }
}
```

better will be:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
    echo "Files Uploaded !" . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];                
    $uploadedFiles[] = $file_name . $sExt;
}

//instead of variable $file1 etc..
foreach($uploadedFiles as $filename){

}
```